# Автоматическое определение типа в сериализации (записи в файл)

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, вывод

Думаю реализовать функцию с таким интерфейсом вызова:

```
'
template<typename typeIn,typename typeWriteFile)
         bool WriteFile(typeIn* InArray, long LenArray){
//1.определить тип 
//2.провести конвертацию typeIn в typeWriteFile 
//3.записать в файл сконвертированный массив

}

// вызов 
float InArray[2048];
WriteFile<float, double>(InArray, 2048);
```

'

Например:

- входной массив `float`, писать в  `double`
- входной массив `double`, писать в `double`
- входной массив `struct {float im; float real;}`, писать последовательно `double double`

Полностью код не нужен, достаточно общих рекомендаций и где почитать.

Comment: Опционально передавать указатель на функцию упаковки например. И если есть функция упаковки, применять ее, а не простой каст типов от к.

Comment: есть decltype и сравнение типов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете реализовать шаблон функции `serialize`:

```
template<typename T>
auto serialize(std::ostream& os, const T& value) -> std::size_t
{
    /* impl */
}
```

, где: os - это поток вывода, value - объект, подлежащий сериализации.

Возможная реализация данной функции:

```
template<typename T>
auto serialize(std::ostream& os, const T& value) -> std::size_t
{
    const auto pos = os.tellp();
    os.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&value), sizeof(T));
    return os.tellp() - pos;
}
```

Эта функция вполне справится с значениями любых целочисленных типов.

Если Вы захотите (или в том возникнет явная необходимость), чтобы значения определенного типа сериализовались отличным от вышеприведенного способа, Вам потребуется перегрузить шаблон функции. Пример для `bool`:

```
auto serialize(std::ostream& os, bool value)
{
    const auto sym = (value) ? 'T' : 'F';
    const auto pos = os.tellp();
    os.write(&sym, sizeof(sym));
    return os.tellp() - pos;
}
```

Очевидно, что подобные функции используются совместно с функциями *десериализации*. Типичный пример - клиент-серверные приложения. Здесь нужно быть очень аккуратным (про [порядок байт](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) я ничего здесь писать не стану, но хочу напомнить), приведу пример:

```
auto serialize(std::ostream& os, const std::string& str) -> std::size_t
{
    const auto pos = os.tellp();
    const auto len = str.size();
    os.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&len), sizeof(len));
    if (len > 0)
    {
        os.write(str.data(), len);
    }
    return os.tellp() - pos;
}
```

Данная функция используется для сериализации объектов типа `std::string` - сперва мы записываем количество символов, содержищихся в строке, а затем непосредственно строку. Казалось бы, что здесь может поломаться? Здесь - ничего, а вот на другой стороне, где размер `std::size` занимает не 4 байта, а 8 (например), произойдет следующее:

1. Будет сделана попытка чтения 8 байт из потока (напоминаю, что на этом шаге мы восстанавливаем значение длины строки), при условии, что мы действительно передавали не пустую строку (или у нас есть еще какие-то данные после строки), данные будут прочтены в *std::size*, значение которого, разумеется, будет невалидным - ведь там мусор.
2. Затем будет сделана попытка чтения N байт из потока, которых там может и не оказаться, все, переданное сообщение не может быть корректно десериализованно.

К чему я веду - используйте целочисленные типы фиксированной длинны. Если Вы изначально наложите ограничение на длину строки (например, условимся, что ее размер должен помещаться в `std::uint16_t`), то данной ошибки уже не произойдет:

```
auto serialize(std::ostream& os, const std::string& str) -> std::size_t
{
    /** code **/
    const auto len = static_cast<std::uint16_t>(str.size());
    /** code **/
}
```

Соответственно, в функции `deserialize(...)` так же используется `std::uin16_t`.

**Сериализация объектов пользовательских классов**

Определите интерфейс, который позволит Вам управлять сериализацией:

```
class ISerializable
{
public:
    virtual auto serialize(std::ostream& os) -> std::size_t = 0;
    virtual auto deserialize(std::istream& is) -> std::size_t = 0;
    virtual auto serializedSize() const noexcept -> std::size_t = 0;
}
```

, и, при необходимости, наследуйтесь от него:

```
class Session : public ISerializable
{
public:
    Session(std::string username, std::string password)
        : m_username(std::move(username))
        , m_password(std::move(password))
    {}

public:
    size_t serialize(std::ostream& os) override
    {
        auto size = 0U;
        size += ::serialize(os, m_username);
        size += ::serialize(os, m_password);
        return size;
    }

protected:
    const std::string m_username;
    const std::string m_password;
};
```

*Прошу заметить, что я переопределил только функцию `serialize(...)`.*

Что касается массивов, о которых Вы упоминали в своем посте: аналогичным образом Вы можете реализовать функцию `serialize` с тремя параметрами - { поток вывода, указатель на начало массива, длинна }, я же посчитал необходимым показать некоторые базовые техники и предупредитить о возможных проблемах.

---

И на последок, хотел бы Вас предупредить о некоторых сложностях: если Вы захотите "научить" функцию serialize работать с классами, унаследованными от `ISerializable`, то очень скоро придете к выводу, что вызывется не та функция, которая Вам бы хотелась. Вот такая перегрузка Вам ничего не даст:

```
auto serialize(std::ostream& os, const ISerializable& object) -> std::size_t
{
    return object.serialize(os);
}
```

Т.е., при вызове функции `serialize(os, session)`, где session - это ссылка на экземпляр класса Session (см. выше), будет инстанцированна и использованна специализация шаблона функции serialize для Session, но никак не та функция, которую мы определили только что.

Возможное решение - реализовать шаблон класса Serializer (или StreamWriter, как Вам угодно), который будет параметризироваться двумя типами:

```
template<typename T, typename P = void>
class StreamWriter
{
public:
    static auto write(std::ostream& os, const T& value) -> std::size_t { /* impl */ }
};
```

Тип `T` - это тип объекта, который будет сериализоваться, `P` - предикат. Это позволит реализовать следующую специализицию:

```
temaplte<typename T>
concept Serializable = std::is_base_of_v<ISerializable, T>;

template<>
class StreamWriter<T, Serializable<T>>
{
public:
    static auto serialize(std::ostream& os, const T& object)
    {
        return object.serialize(os);
    }
}
```

Все :)